# ORA-00997 illegal use of Long datatype Oracle DBlink-msSQLserver

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

i want to migrate data from MS SQL server(2012) to oracle(19c) so i use the oracle gateway (ODBC) to achieve this migration but it failed and i get the following error :

> SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype 00997. 00000 -
>   "illegal use of LONG datatype"

My Query :

```
INSERT INTO ADDRESS (ID,ADDRESS,REMARK)
SELECT "ID","ADDRESS","REMARK" FROM ADDRESS@MSSQL;
```

Where ADDRESS (oracle table ) and ADDRESS--->VARCHAR2(2000)

and

ADDRESS(MS SQL Server table) and ADDRESS--->nvarchar(-1).

i also tried to :

```
create table test as select id,address,remark from address@MSSQL;
```

but same error as illegal use of LONG data type.

Comment: how much data are we talking about?

Comment: actually it will be a routine job in future, so i prefer to select insert data using Oracle gateway....The volume would be around 500k rows daily.

Comment: i would look at GoldenGate...instead of paying money on the gateway, better to spend money on a real replication solution